# What is the pythonic way to reverse a defaultdict(list)?

Tags: python, list, collections, reverse, defaultdict

What is the pythonic way to reverse a `defaultdict(list)`?

I could iterating through the defaultdict and creating a new defaultdict.
Is there any other way? Is this pythonic:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = defaultdict(list)
>>> y = [[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]]
>>> z= ['a','b']
>>> for i,j in zip(y,z):
...     x[j] = i
... 
>>> x
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 6]})
>>> x2 = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in x.items():
...     for i in v:
...             x2[i].append(k)
... 
>>> x2
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['a'], 2: ['a'], 3: ['a','b'], 4: ['a','b'], 5: ['b'], 6: ['b']})
```

Comment: It's not clear why you need a defaultdict here.

Comment: the original default dict has a unique identifier for same things with different name. But to look for the identifier using one of the name, i have to do a value to key search each time, so using a reverse defaultdict optimizes my code.

Comment: Shouldn't the output for `x` be `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 4, 5, 6]})`?  No idea where the `7, 8` part of the given output came from.

Comment: ah, forgot to change appropriately ;P , poor cut-and-paste ability...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the *best* way is to simply loop as you did:

```
target = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in original.items():
    for value in values:
        target[value].append(key)
```

Alternatively you could avoid the inner `for`:

```
for key, values in original.items():
    target.update(zip(values, [key] * len(values)))
```

Or using `itertools.repeat`:

```
import itertools as it

for key, values in original.items():
    target.update(zip(values, it.repeat(key)))
```

However these last solutions only work for the simple case where values in different lists are distinct.

---

Remember that pythonic doesn't have any definite meaning. *I*'d consider python a solution that is:

1. Readable
2. Correctly use the language features
3. Correctly use the built-ins/standard library
4. Efficient

And the points are in order of importance. Efficience is last because it is most often implied by point 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more pythonic or just more cryptic?

```
map(lambda (i, k): x2[i].append(k), [(i, k) for i in v for k, v in x.items()])
```

Following variant is required for python 3, and is less clear:

```
map(lambda i_k: x2[i_k[0]].append(i_k[1]), [(i, k) for i in v for k, v in x.items()])
```

Writing this, I've concluded this is probably about the least pythonic way of doing it. But possibly educational; it was for me.

***Edit**: Don't do this.*

Comment: Using a function, which has side-effects, in `map` is definitely not pythonic, I think :)

Comment: @thefourtheye... I had hoped for a dictionary comprehension with defaultdict functionality. map and lambda was the best I could come up with, and I do agree this is worse than OP's original. Even if it did work

Comment: Note that this *utterly* fails in python3 (even your so-called variant for python3). The `map` will never execute any function call since it is lazy.

Comment: Thank you @Bakuriu. I don't have python3 to test. But this is the best reason yet not to do it, as presumably stop working in 2to3